# JQuery scrolltop is scrolling up rather than down

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

For some reason all of my Scrolltop jquery functions are working great on this page: http://www.nvrentals.net/ -except for the scroll function that's applied to each "Client icon".

Here's my goal: in the mobile phone width (the site is responsive) - when a user clicks on the "Concert Halls" icon, they should scroll down to the open panel below....

Problem: right now, when it's clicked, the user scrolls up to a random spot on the page.

I can't figure out what's going on - the stuff works fine in JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gGuDF/

Here's my JS:

```
 $('.scrollerr').click(function(e){

    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$('.scrollee').position().top}, 600);

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried,

```
$('.scrollee').offset().top
```

I havent tested it, or maybe try this,

```
 var $scrollee = $(this).find('.scrollee');

 var newScroll = parseInt( $scrollee.position().top ) 
    + parseInt( $scrollee.parent().scrollTop() );

  $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:newScroll}, 600);
```

OR

```
 $('.scrollerr .scrollee').click(function(e){

$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$(this).position().top}, 600);

e.preventDefault();
```

});